# When demanding Vassalization, how is the distance calculated

Tags: stellaris

When demanding vassalization, a number of factors determine whether the other empire will accept your demand:

[image]

One of the biggest factors is "Distance". What does this distance signify?

It does not appear to be distance to my closest planet: in the screenshot bellow the only planet of this empire is in the same system as one of my planets (since I just liberated them, and I took over another planet in the same system in this war)

I don't think it is distance to my capital either, the system is fairly close.

As per this question [How to get other empires to agree to "demand vassalization" peacefully?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265967/how-to-get-other-empires-to-agree-to-demand-vassalization-peacefully)
liberating planets should make it easy to peacefully vassalize them, yet this almost never seems to work in my case.

[image]

Here I reloaded and liberated a different planet in the same system. The distance stat appears to be gone. (Still not enough to demand vassalization unfortunatelly)

Comment: It might just be bugged.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the Contacts > Empires tab, you'll see a 'Distance to' column. If you hover this number it should tell you the system that it is calculating the distance to from. For example, I was around 280 away from one Empire based of of my Home System, but I then colonized a system close-by and it changed to ~70 distance from that system.

Answer (score 0):

The distance thing certainly is a bug.

I also miss the opinion modifier for your vassalization request. A liberated empire should really like you and thus provide a big bonus. Considering,they have a friendly attitude, you certainly should get more positive modifiers than that. Another factor might be your empire ethics, which may prevent the vassalization. Peaceful vassalization works best with a xenophile empire.

In my personal experience of about 80 hours, I have to say the current diplomacy system is in need of a heavy rework, just demanding vassalization as a war goal is by far the most efficient way of expanding.